# Microsoft graph API: Create Reply draft and Send mail OR Direct reply not working

Tags: c#, json, curl, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to reply to mail but it is not working

**STEP 1 (CURL REQUEST)** -Create a draft message in JSON format to reply to an existing message.

```
curl --location 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "subject":"From Postmen1",
    "importance":"Low",
    "body":{
        "contentType":"HTML",
        "content":"They were <b>awesome</b>!"
    },
    "toRecipients":[
        {
            "emailAddress":{
                "address":"dd43@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

Getting response like this
[image]

**STEP 2 (CURL REQUEST)** Send an existing draft message

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id OF PREVIOUS RESPONSE}/send' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
--header 'content-type: application/json'
```

**STEP 3 (CURL REQUEST)** - Create a draft message in JSON format to reply to an existing message.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id OF STEP 1 RESPONSE}/createReply' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data ''
```

**GETTING ERROR**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
        "message": "The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties."
    }
}
```

**STEP 3 ALTERNATE WAY** -Reply in JSON format to an existing message

```
curl --location 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/id OF STEP 1 RESPONSE/reply' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "message": {
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "dd43@gmail.com",
                    "name": "dd43@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "comment": "Samantha, would you name the group please?"
}'
```

I am not able to understand the issue. Error is not specifying any specific issue

I want to create a reply of first mail and then want to send mail in same thread

Answer (score 1):

The message id is not immutable, so it's changed after you send the mail.

When creating a draft message you can set `Prefer: IdType="ImmutableId"` header

```
curl --location 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--header 'Prefer: IdType="ImmutableId"' \
--data-raw '{
    "subject":"From Postmen1",
    "importance":"Low",
    "body":{
        "contentType":"HTML",
        "content":"They were <b>awesome</b>!"
    },
    "toRecipients":[
        {
            "emailAddress":{
                "address":"belishdev1@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

Then step 3 should work

Example for SDK v5:

```
var messageBody = new Message
{
    Subject = "",
    Importance = Importance.Low,
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = "They were <b>awesome</b>!",
    },
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "belishdev1@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    }
};
var message = await graphClient.Me.Messages.PostAsync(messageBody, rc =>
{
    rc.Headers.Add("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"");
});
await graphClient.Me.Messages[message.Id].Send.PostAsync();
var replyBody = new CreateReplyPostRequestBody
{
    Comment = "reply text"
};
await graphClient.Me.Messages[message.Id].CreateReply.PostAsync(replyBody);
```

Resources:

[Get immutable identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id)

Comment: I am using GraphAPI sdk in c#, Any suggestion for that?
`TokenProvider provider = new TokenProvider();
                provider.token = outlookIntegrationModel.Access_token;
                var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(provider);
                graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);`

Comment: @HardikMasalawala added example for C# (SDK v5)

Comment: I am adding attachment too,I have checked my mail, my reply draft created successfully but it is not sending due to error

Comment: @HardikMasalawala Hard to say without the details of the error.

Comment: How can I send mail in same thread? is there any way?